# Why is my AJAX call success function not firing a java script alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url: '../api/notifications/deleteNotification?userId=' + userId + '&notificationId=' + notificationId,
   type: 'DELETE',
   success: function()
   {
       CreateNotificationTree(userId);
       alert('Delete successful.');
   },
   failure: function()
   {
       alert('Delete failed.');
   }
});
```

The function `CreateNotificationTree(userId);` that is inside the success function of the ajax call above DOES fire. However, the Alert is not firing after. Does anybody know why? I have tried to use multiple browsers as well.

EDIT - found out I'm running into this error when the AJAX call executes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined kendo.web.min.js:23
(anonymous function) kendo.web.min.js:23
p.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.p.each jquery.min.js:2
g.extend._attachUids kendo.web.min.js:23
g.extend.init kendo.web.min.js:22
(anonymous function) kendo.web.min.js:9
p.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.p.each jquery.min.js:2
$.fn.(anonymous function) kendo.web.min.js:9
CreateNotificationTree NotificationsTreeView.js:17
(anonymous function) NotificationsTreeView.js:60
k jquery.min.js:2
l.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
y jquery.min.js:2
d
```

Comment: And you don't have errors in the console ?

Comment: If that function throws an error, the alert will never be shown.

Comment: Are you sure?  jQuery tends to fail silently if you aren't paying close attention

Comment: Do you have a "Throw" in CreateNotificationTree?

Comment: It is possible that CreateNotificationTree(userId) is running successfully up until a point where it fails.  Are you sure that the entire function completed successfully?

Comment: I actually did run into an error after I did what Sushanth mentioned. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined. I'm taking a look at it right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Log the error to your console.

**You do not see the alert if ajax fails method as `jQuery` does not identify the `failure` method.**

Use a **`error`** callback to log the error.

Also use `console.log` instead of `alert` which is annoying and stops the flow of execution

```
failure: function(){
   alert('Delete failed.');
}
```

supposed to be

```
error: function(){
   alert('Delete failed.');
}
```

And use `done` and `fail` instead of `success` and `error` callbacks as the latter as deprecated as of version `1.8`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../api/notifications/deleteNotification?userId=' 
               + userId + '&notificationId=' + notificationId,
    type: 'DELETE'
}).done(function () {
    CreateNotificationTree(userId);
    console.log('Delete successful.');
}).fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
    console.log("Error : " + error);
});
```

Use the `arguments` that are passed to the callbacks and you ll be able to pinpoint the error.

Comment: thanks for the response! im giving this a try right now and will report back in a few.

Comment: I updated my OP with the error message I'm getting. I'm not sure what that means, though.

Comment: @Rj. Looks like your ajax is a request ok. And error inside `CreateNotificationTree` method is the source for the error. You seem to be trying to access a property on an undefined object

Comment: that was it. I needed to destroy the kendo tree view from the DOM because I was duplicating it when I was trying to do a data refresh. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Rj. Glad to have helped :)